# How to scrape a table from a webpage and exclude specific tables neseted inside tables<td> tag

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wish to scrape a table from a specific webpage. The issue is that some of the table's td contains a nested span tag containing another nested table.

The webpage that I want to scrape from is the following [Click here](http://eciresults.nic.in/Statewises26.htm) .

I have included a small sample of the table that I want to scrape with the nested table contained within span tag with a class tooltip-icon. How can I exclude the contents inside these specific span tags when **scraping** the whole table

```
<tr style="font-size:12px;">
<td align="left">Abhanpur</td>
<td align="center">53</td>
<td align="left">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>DHANENDRA SAHU</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:top"><span class="tooltip-icon" style="display:block">i</span>
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        <h3>Assembly Election Result 2013</h3>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Party</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td>Indian National Congress</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Result</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td>WON</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Margin</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td>8354</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
<td align="left">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Indian National Congress</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:top"><span class="tooltip-icon" style="display:block">i</span>
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        <h3>Current Assembly Election Result</h3>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Leading In</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Won In</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td>68</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Trailing In</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
<td align="left">CHANDRASHEKHAR SAHU - CHAMPU BHAIYYA</td>
<td align="left">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Bharatiya Janata Party</td>
                <td style="vertical-align:top"><span class="tooltip-icon" style="display:block">i</span>
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        <h3>Current Assembly Election Result</h3>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Leading In</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Won In</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td>15</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Trailing In</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
<td align="right">23471 </td>
<td align="center">Result Declared</td>
<td align="center" style="background-color: lightgray;">DHANENDRA SAHU</td>
<td align="center" style="background-color: lightgray;">Indian National Congress</td>
<td align="center" style="background-color: lightgray;">8354</td>
```

I am also including the full python script I currently use to scrape the table. I have successfully scrape the whole table but unable to exclude the nested span and table content.

[full scraper code here](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/0cbc8887-a6d9-4c56-94a8-cb385d18e3b5/)

The Out put that I am currently getting in a csv format is as follows (Just the sample row out of the whole set). In the 3rd column the span tag also gets **scraped** as indicated by **"iAssembly Election Result"**

```
Abhanpur,53,DHANENDRA SAHUiAssembly Election Result 2013Party:Indian National CongressResult:WONMargin:8354,DHANENDRA SAHU,iAssembly Election Result 2013Party:Indian National CongressResult:WONMargin:8354,Party,:,Indian National Congress,Result,:,WON,Margin,:,8354,Indian National CongressiCurrent Assembly Election ResultLeading In:0Won In:68Trailing In:0,Indian National Congress,iCurrent Assembly Election ResultLeading In:0Won In:68Trailing In:0,Leading In,:,0,Won In,:,68,Trailing In,:,0,CHANDRASHEKHAR SAHU - CHAMPU BHAIYYA,Bharatiya Janata PartyiCurrent Assembly Election ResultLeading In:0Won In:15Trailing In:0,Bharatiya Janata Party,iCurrent Assembly Election ResultLeading In:0Won In:15Trailing In:0,Leading In,:,0,Won In,:,15,Trailing In,:,0,23471                                             ,Result Declared,DHANENDRA SAHU,Indian National Congress,8354,
```

The expected out put is to scrape the table excluding the span tags and its nested tables. for example

```
Abhanpur, 53 , DHANENDRA SAHU, Indian National Congress, CHANDRASHEKHAR SAHU - CHAMPU BHAIYYA, Bharatiya Janata Party , 23471, Result Declared
```

Any help on this would be very helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just my preference, but whenever I see `<table>` tags, I utilise Pandas to do the parsing, then just manipulate the dataframe as needed. It also allows you to write to file in one line:

```
import pandas as pd

results_df = pd.DataFrame()
url_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
url = 'http://eciresults.nic.in/Statewises26.htm'

dfs = pd.read_html(url)
df = dfs[0]

idx = df[df[0] == '1\xa02\xa03\xa04\xa05\xa06\xa07\xa08\xa09\xa0Next >>'].index[0]
cols = list(df.iloc[idx-1,:])


df.columns = cols

df = df[df['Const. No.'].notnull()]
df = df.loc[df['Const. No.'].str.isdigit()].reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')

df['Leading Candidate'] = df['Leading Candidate'].str.split('i',expand=True)[0]
df['Leading Party'] = df['Leading Party'].str.split('iCurrent',expand=True)[0]
df['Trailing Party'] = df['Trailing Party'].str.split('iCurrent',expand=True)[0]
df['Trailing Candidate'] = df['Trailing Candidate'].str.split('iAssembly',expand=True)[0]

results_df = results_df.append(df)

for x in url_list:
    url = 'http://eciresults.nic.in/Statewises26%s.htm' %x
    print ('Processed %s' %url)
    dfs = pd.read_html(url)
    df = dfs[0]

    df.columns = cols

    df = df[df['Const. No.'].notnull()]
    df = df.loc[df['Const. No.'].str.isdigit()].reset_index(drop=True)
    df = df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')

    df['Leading Candidate'] = df['Leading Candidate'].str.split('i',expand=True)[0]
    df['Leading Party'] = df['Leading Party'].str.split('iCurrent',expand=True)[0]
    df['Trailing Party'] = df['Trailing Party'].str.split('iCurrent',expand=True)[0]
    df['Trailing Candidate'] = df['Trailing Candidate'].str.split('iAssembly',expand=True)[0]

    results_df = results_df.append(df).reset_index(drop=True)

results_df.to_csv('Chhattisgarh_cand.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
  Constituency Const. No.       Leading Candidate                    Leading Party                    Trailing Candidate            Trailing Party Margin           Status          Winning Candidate             Winning Party Margin
0     Abhanpur         53          DHANENDRA SAHU         Indian National Congress  CHANDRASHEKHAR SAHU - CHAMPU BHAIYYA    Bharatiya Janata Party  23471  Result Declared             DHANENDRA SAHU  Indian National Congress   8354
1      Ahiwara         67        GURU RUDRA KUMAR         Indian National Congress            RAJMAHANT SANWLA RAM DAHRE    Bharatiya Janata Party  31687  Result Declared  RAJMAHNT SANWLA RAM DAHRE    Bharatiya Janata Party  31676
2     Akaltara         33           SAURABH SINGH           Bharatiya Janata Party                            RICHA JOGI       Bahujan Samaj Party   1854  Result Declared             CHUNNILAL SAHU  Indian National Congress  21693
3    Ambikapur         10               T.S. BABA         Indian National Congress                      ANURAG SINGH DEO    Bharatiya Janata Party  39624  Result Declared                   T.S.BABA  Indian National Congress  19558
4     Antagarh         79               ANOOP NAG         Indian National Congress                         VIKRAM USENDI    Bharatiya Janata Party  13414  Result Declared              VIKRAM USENDI    Bharatiya Janata Party   5171
5        Arang         52  DR. SHIVKUMAR DAHARIYA         Indian National Congress                         SANJAY DHIDHI    Bharatiya Janata Party  25077  Result Declared           NAVEEN MARKANDEY    Bharatiya Janata Party  13774
6  Baikunthpur          3        AMBICA SINGH DEO         Indian National Congress                     BHAIYALAL RAJWADE    Bharatiya Janata Party   5339  Result Declared          BHAIYALAL RAJWADE    Bharatiya Janata Party   1069
7  Balodabazar         45     PRAMOD KUMAR SHARMA  Janta Congress Chhattisgarh (J)                       JANAK RAM VERMA  Indian National Congress   2129  Result Declared            JANAK RAM VERMA  Indian National Congress   9977
8        Basna         40  DEVENDRA BAHADUR SINGH         Indian National Congress                        SAMPAT AGRAWAL               Independent  17508  Result Declared        RUPKUMARI CHOUDHARY    Bharatiya Janata Party   6239
9       Bastar         85       BAGHEL LAKHESHWAR         Indian National Congress                    DR. SUBHAU KASHYAP    Bharatiya Janata Party  33471  Result Declared          BAGHEL LAKHESHWAR  Indian National Congress  19168
```

Comment: while running the code I faced with an error :-Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vigneshkumark/PycharmProjects/untitled1/new.py", line 8, in<module>
    idx = df[df[0] == '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Next >>'].index[0]
  File "C:\Users\vigneshkumark\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3958, in __getitem__
  return getitem(key)
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0               
Moreover in your output in the trailing candidate column I need only the names of the candidate. 4 row o/p expected 'ANURAG SINGH DEO'

Comment: If you could make the necessary correction it would be very much helpful for me. Thanks @chitown88

Comment: what version of pandas do you have installed?

Comment: pandas 0.24.2 is the version I used

Comment: @VigneshKumar give it another shot.

Comment: @chitown88 as you told I tried several times but its throwing the same error!!! Help me out from this it would be helpful for me.

Comment: I made an edit, which is why I asked you to try out the code again. So I’m assuming you re-tried the edited code. With that being said, I’ll try a different method and edit the code above again when I get into work

Comment: Sure.Thanks @chitown88

Comment: @VigneshKumar, updated the code. Try it again and let me know if it worked

Comment: @chitown88 Now the code is working only for that url alone.when I want to loop into the all other pages available in the webpage it shows the same error as before I attach pages which I want to scrap[link](http://eciresults.nic.in/Statewises261.htm)[link](http://eciresults.nic.in/Statewises262.htm)[link](http://eciresults.nic.in/Statewises263.htm)[link](http://eciresults.nic.in/Statewises264.htm)[link](http://eciresults.nic.in/Statewises265.htm)[link](http://eciresults.nic.in/Statewises266.htm)[link](http://eciresults.nic.in/Statewises267.htm)[link](http://eciresults.nic.in/Statewises268.htm)

Comment: @chitown88 Now its working for that webpage.In that there is drop down containing select state. now we have scraped for "Chhattisgarh" state. But when I change the url for "Madhya Pradesh" state its throwing error. I want to scarp all the data which is available for  "Chhattisgarh,Madhya Pradesh,Mizoram,Rajasthan,Telangana" these are the drop down values available in the webpage as if now. Even if the drop state increase in future it must scarpe all the data. The code which you provided me for "Chhattisgarh" state works perfectly,thank you for that. What I told before is my objective.Thanks

Comment: @chitown88 did you find any solution for what I asked?

Comment: @chitown88 with your code I'm able to scrape into all the pages. But when I use this  URL I'm unable to scrape. The URL is(https://web.archive.org/web/20140528015357/http://eciresults.nic.in/statewiseS26.htm?st=S26) in this there is no need of splitting the string. But in case in future, there is a need I want to scape it so as before from your code. I had used beautifulsoup its working fine. But with pandas, it is not so. The updated code was[https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/3ae070d2-4ffe-4071-90a4-3a1f4439f22a/?m=Saved%20fiddle]. I request you to help me out in this!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with pandas, using this:

```
import pandas as pd
page = pd.read_html('http://eciresults.nic.in/Statewises26.htm')
my_table = page[5]
```

That gets you a pandas dataframe containing the table you're interested in, I believe. If you try:

```
my_table.iloc[[7]]
```

The output is:

```
7   Abhanpur    53  DHANENDRA SAHUiAssembly Election Result 2013Pa...   Indian National CongressiCurrent Assembly Elec...   CHANDRASHEKHAR SAHU - CHAMPU BHAIYYA    Bharatiya Janata PartyiCurrent Assembly Electi...   23471   Result Declared     DHANENDRA SAHU  Indian National Congress    8354    NaN     NaN
```

If that's what you are after, you can clean up your table using standard pandas methods.